# O que é SSL Pinning?

Tags: segurança, ssl, cliente-servidor

Recentemente estava assistindo a um vídeo que mencionou brevemente o termo "SSL Pinning" para descrever uma medida (entendida por mim como de segurança) para estabelecer um mecanismo de comunicação mais seguro e, provavelmente, criptografado, entre uma aplicação cliente (como um aplicativo móvel) e um servidor. No entanto, além de mencionar o termo, nenhum outro detalhe foi dado.

Então, fiquei com as dúvidas:

- O que é SSL Pinning?
- Brevemente, como funciona?
- Qual é o objetivo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em um SSL "normal" (sem *pinning*), o *handshake* (a "conversa inicial" que o cliente e o servidor fazem para se conectar) possui [várias etapas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake), e em uma delas o servidor envia para o cliente o seu certificado digital.

O cliente então verifica se este certificado é confiável. Para isso, ele vê se o certificado foi emitido (assinado) por alguma autoridade certificadora em que ele confia.

Os browsers já vêm com uma lista pré-instalada de autoridades certificadoras confiáveis (que você pode gerenciar nas configurações, adicionando ou removendo certificados, por exemplo). Se o certificado do servidor foi assinado por alguma dessas autoridades, ele também verifica se o domínio do certificado bate com a URL do site, e se tudo estiver certo, o certificado é considerado OK (para saber mais: https://stackoverflow.com/q/188266).

Outras aplicações costumam ter esta lista de certificados confiáveis em algum arquivo de configuração (*trust store*, *cacerts*, cada uma chama de um jeito).

Como curiosidade (só para citar um exemplo), o certificado do SOpt (que você pode ver clicando no cadeado do browser) é assim (eu abri no Chrome do Windows, a interface pode variar):

[image: certificado stackexchange]

Ele foi emitido para o domínio stackexchange.com mas é possível colocar mais de uma URL:

[image: multi domínio]

Veja que o domínio *.stackoverflow.com faz parte do certificado, por isso o browser considera que ele bate com a URL pt.stackoverflow.com e portanto é válido.

E também podemos ver a cadeia:

[image: cadeia]

Ou seja, ele foi emitido pela Let's Encrypt (que é chamado também de "Autoridade Intermediária"), que por sua vez foi emitido pelo DST Root CA X3 (a "Autoridade Raiz", pois acima dela não tem ninguém). E ambos estão na lista de certificados confiáveis que você pode ver nas configurações do browser:

[image: autoridades intermediárias]

[image: autoridades certificadores]

---

#### Tá, mas e o *pinning*?

O SSL pinning (ou **HPKP** - [HTTP Public Key Pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning)) pode ser visto tanto como uma "checagem adicional no cliente", ou como um *bypass* na checagem do servidor.

É basicamente uma verificação feita no lado do cliente. [Aqui tem um exemplo com código em Kotlin](https://medium.com/@zhangqichuan/explain-ssl-pinning-with-simple-codes-eaee95b70507), vou colocá-lo aqui de forma mais resumida:

```kt
val pinnedCertificate = // certificado que quero "pinnar"
val url = URL("https://www.google.com")
val httpsUrlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
httpsUrlConnection.connect()
// se o certificado do servidor é o mesmo que eu "pinnei"
if (httpsUrlConnection.serverCertificates.contains(pinnedCertificate)) {
    // usa a conexão normalmente
    Log.d("Pinning", "Server certificates validation successful")
} else {
    Log.d("Pinning", "Server certificates validation failed")
    throw SSLException("Server certificates validation failed for google.com")
}
```

Ou seja, além do SSL handshake que já é feito normalmente ao se acessar um site HTTPS, o cliente ainda faz outra verificação adicional no certificado do servidor.

Então mesmo que a conexão esteja sofrendo um ataque *man in the middle*, no qual o atacante gerou um certificado falso (conforme explicado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479814/112052)), este certificado falso não baterá com o que o cliente está verificando.

Vale lembrar também que esta técnica pode ser aplicada com apenas as chaves públicas em vez do certificado inteiro (para ser mais preciso, o que é "pinnado" neste caso é o hash da chave pública). Isso deixaria as coisas um pouco "menos *hardcoded*", pois certificados podem ser renovados usando o mesmo par de chaves (se isso é bom ou ruim, [é outra história](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/27810)).

No caso dos browsers, esta lista *hardcoded* de chaves públicas era enviada em um header HTTP, juntamente com um prazo de validade. Assim, o cliente deveria usar esta lista enquanto o prazo fosse válido - o processo é descrito [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning#Mechanism):

> *The server communicates the HPKP policy to the user agent via an HTTP response header field named Public-Key-Pins (or Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only for reporting-only purposes).**
>
> *The HPKP policy specifies hashes of the subject public key info of one of the certificates in the website's authentic X.509 public key certificate chain (and at least one backup key) in pin-sha256 directives, and a period of time during which the user agent shall enforce public key pinning in max-age directive, optional includeSubDomains directive to include all subdomains (of the domain that sent the header) in pinning policy and optional report-uri directive with URL where to send pinning violation reports. At least one of the public keys of the certificates in the certificate chain needs to match a pinned public key in order for the chain to be considered valid by the user agent.*

Detalhe que nesta lista poderia ter somente o hash da Autoridade Certificadora, ou das intermediárias, ou do certificado do servidor. No caso do certificado da Stack Exchange, por exemplo, a lista poderia ter somente a chave do certificado da Let's Encrypt, ou somente da DST Root CA X3, ou somente do próprio site (ao colocar da DST Root, estou dizendo que qualquer certificado emitido por ela seria válido, o que seria menos restritivo do que colocar somente o certificado do próprio servidor).

---

Claro, você pode imaginar os problemas de ter uma lista *hardcoded* no cliente. Cada vez que o domínio sendo acessado trocar de certificado, você vai ter que atualizar esta lista no cliente (no caso desta verificação ser via código).

E no caso do servidor enviar a lista em um header HTTP, bastaria que alguém invadisse o servidor e fizesse-o "pinnar" seus próprios certificados falsos, e os clientes só passariam a aceitar estes.

Há uma discussão mais detalhada sobre o assunto [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29988).

---

De qualquer forma, o HPKP é obsoleto e foi removido dos *browsers*, que atualmente estão - não sei se todos - usando [CT - *Certificate Transparency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency) - que por sua vez, segundo a [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning), estará obsoleto a partir de 2021, quando espera-se que todos passem a usar [*Signed Certificate Timestamps (SCTs)*](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/faq#TOC-What-is-an-SCT-).

Answer (score 6):

Um certificado SSL possui uma cadeia de assinatura, que começa numa entidade certificadora raiz (CA root), que assinou certificado A, que assinou certificado B, até chegar no certificado final.

Os browsers têm uma lista de CA roots embutida. Qualquer certificado cuja cadeia *inicie* num CA root conhecido, é aceito como bom, não interessa quantos intermediários hajam.

Porém isto deixa margem para alguns ataques, por exemplo se alguém tomar conta do seu domínio e assinar um certificado novo usando Let's Encrypt, o certificado "falso" ainda é considerado válido.

O SSL pinning é uma checagem adicional de um ou mais certificados *intermediários*, o que garante que o certificado foi assinado pela entidade esperada. Por exemplo, se eu comprei o certificado da SnakeOil, e faço o SSL pinning da SnakeOil, um novo certificado assinado pela Let's Encrypt não seria aceito.

Outra possibilidade é fazer o SSL pinning de um certificado-mãe, que lhe pertence. Por exemplo, você tem muitos domínios, então assina os diversos certificados de cada site usando o certificado-mãe. Os certificados de site podem ter validade mais curta e serem trocados periodicamente, mas o pinning do certificado-mãe garante que só é aceito um certificado que foi gerado por você.